# Copy-Item using a list.txt with wildcards as reference

Tags: powershell, file, wildcard, copy-item

I have a folder with millions of files, and I would like to use PowerShell to move the files from a txt file with wildcards that looks for the content of a filename.

I have used the script pasted below, and it only works with the first line in the text file.

Example:

I want to find filename1 and it copies all the files containing filename1.

But if I add more wildcards in the .txt file

```
*filename1*
*filename2*
*filename3*
```

it still only finds the filename1 files, and does not proceed to the next line.

```
$source = "c:\temp\source"
$destination = "c:\temp\destination"
$file_list = Get-Content "c:\temp\file_list.txt" 

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $source = $source + "\$file"
    Copy-Item $source $destination
}
```

Comment: when you say "files containing" ... do you mean file NAMES or the content of the files?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the variable `$source` inside the loop. With the changed source path your code doesn't find any other file to copy after the first iteration, because there are no files with paths like

```
c:\temp\source\*filename1*\*filename2*
c:\temp\source\*filename1*\*filename2*\*filename3*
...
```

Change this

```
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $source = $source + "\$file"
    Copy-Item $source $destination
}
```

into this

```
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    Copy-Item "$source\$file" $destination
}
```

and the problem will disappear.